# php unserialize working differently across machines

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, php-5.3

I have an array that has been serialized by php, the result is:

```
unserialize('a:2:{s:13:"custom_basket";a:1:{i:280583837398;a:4:{s:12:"product_name";s:0:"";s:8:"quantity";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";d:38.649999999999999;s:11:"description";a:7:{s:2:"id";s:12:"280583837398";s:3:"sku";s:0:"";s:4:"site";s:2:"UK";s:12:"condition_id";s:4:"1000";s:14:"transaction_id";s:12:"773563256018";s:8:"platform";s:4:"eBay";s:18:"order_line_item_id";s:25:"280583837398-773563256018";}}}s:6:"basket";a:0:{}}')
```

When I use my machine running php 5.3.5 I get:

> Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 46 of 405 bytes

When the dude next to me runs it on his machine running 5.3.6 he gets the array back out.  Our server that runs php 5.3.4 also successfully unserializes the array.

The error that I get points to the first key in the second array `i:280583837398` if I change this too `s:12:"280583837398"` my machine can now unserialize the array successfully.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening.  I have no idea if it is the php version, I just noticed that I had a different version to the two successful machines so thought it worth mentioning.

I am running MAMP PRO on Snow Leopard if that helps.

Comment: Not sure if it's the version or not, but maybe the different versions handle ints differently. It seems like you understand s means a string of x length, hence s:12 is a string of length 12. But if php is trying to parse that as a 32 bit int, then it may fail. Also, is your machine 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Hi Matt, my machine is 64-bit. Its an Intel Core i5 Imac.

Comment: I did not realise that my machine might fail on an integer that big, just editing the int down to 9 characters makes the unserialize succeed.  Is this a common issue and is there a workaround?

Comment: Also, how can my machine serialize the array in the first place but not unserialize it, are the ints handled differently in the two processes?

Comment: I really don't know how php handles it. You can try to upgrade  and see if it works, but thats kind of a weird issue. I guess you can always convert the int to a string before you serialize.

Comment: Hi Matt, if you add your answer I will mark it correct as after digging it turns out my MAMP PRO is the i386 version not the 64-bit version if that would cause this error.

Comment: yea then that would do it. You can also get around it by converting it to a double first. So it would be serialized to d:280583837398, which would work when you unserialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the version or not, but maybe the different versions handle ints differently. It seems like you understand s means a string of x length, hence s:12 is a string of length 12. But if php is trying to parse that as a 32 bit int, then it may fail.

Comment: Thanks for helping, we ended up adding "e" to the front so that serialize makes it a string instead

Answer (score 0):

280583837398 is a pretty big number, maybe your machine tries to fit it in an `integer` which supports numbers up to 32 bits.

You probably need `long` to store this one.

Thats all I can tell from this for now.

Comment: PHP doesn't have `longs`, but it has 32 and 64 bit `ints`, depending on the architecture.